# Compare array lists with the next one in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to compare lists with others in order to merge if their numbers (id_article) are the same.
In my example, I would like to obtain this final array list :

****Final ****

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_article] => 1
            [quantite] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_article] => 3
            [quantite] => 1
        )

}
```

**INITIAL**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_article] => 1
            [quantite] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_article] => 1
            [quantite] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_article] => 3
            [quantite] => 1
        )

)
```

I tried with next() and current() but didn't work in this case.

Thanks in advance for help, advice or others examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'id_article' => 1,
        'quantite' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'id_article' => 1,
        'quantite' => 3,
    ),
    array(
        'id_article' => 3,
        'quantite' => 1,
    ),
);

$b = array();

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    if (array_key_exists($v['id_article'], $b)) {
        $b[$v['id_article']]['quantite'] += $v['quantite'];
    } else {
        $b[$v['id_article']] = $v;
    }
}

return array_values($b);
```

Comment: Thx @exec I use this solution for my project.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do some loop jobs:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (isset($result[$value['id_article']])) {
         $result[$value['id_article']] += $value['quantite'];
    } else {
         $result[$value['id_article']] = $value['quantite'];
    }  
}

$output = array();
foreach ($result as $id => $value) {
   $output[] = array('id_article' => $id, 'quantite' => $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
echo "<pre>";
$arr_input = array(
                array
                    (
                        "id_article" => 1,
                        "quantite" => 2
                    ),
                array
                    (
                        "id_article" => 1,
                        "quantite" => 3
                    ),
                array
                    (
                        "id_article" => 3,
                        "quantite" => 1
                    )
           );               

$arr_temp = array();    
foreach($arr_input as $arr)
{
    if(isset($arr_temp[$arr['id_article']]))
    {
        $arr_temp[$arr['id_article']] += $arr['quantite'];
    }
    else
    {
        $arr_temp[$arr['id_article']] = $arr['quantite'];
    }   
}   


$arr_ouput = array();
foreach($arr_temp as $key=>$val)
{
    $arr_output[] = array("id_article" => $key, "quantite" => $val);
}

print_r($arr_output);
```